# jQuery autocomplete ON multiple fields as well as TO multiple fields

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to use autocomplete on a page which has a large number if input fields (generated from mySQL) which all need the same lookup.
A single autocomplete just uses

```
$( "#surname" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
```

so I thought of doing..

```
$( "input" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
```

That's fine BUT my lookup query is returning a second variable which I need to put into another field on the form. The lookup field and the other field have related names e.f. bar2 and bar3email. Using the "input" option, how can I tell which field generated the lookup so I can then work out the field name where I want the second variable to go??

Trying to put it more simply, if I do an autocomplete in a field called 'bar2' and fill it with a name, I want the second returned variable (the relevant email) to be put in a field called 'bar2email'.

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Supply a callback function to handle the select event as an init option or bind to the select event.  See [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) documentation on the select event.

The select event will pass an `event` object.  The event object has the property named `target`. You can use this property to determine the which DOM element initiated the event.  Something LIKE this will work.

```
$( "input" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
select: function(event,ui){
         var targetFieldId = event.target.id; //get id of DOM element ie bar2
         var relatedField = document.getElementById(targetFieldId+'email'); //get related field
         relatedField.val(ui.item.value);  // assuming second varible is value
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
Realised I could identify the triggering field with
$(this).attr('id')
So this...

```
$( 'input[type=text].ck' ).autocomplete({  
source: "search.php",  
minLength: 1,  
delay: 250,  
select: function( event, ui ) {  
var destfield = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'mail';  
log(destfield, ui.item.Email);  
}  
});
```

... returns the item from the autocomplete (ui.item.Email) along with the id of the variable that triggered it (destfield, derived from $(this).attr('id') )